# Access to custom Obj-C category from Swift

Tags: categories, swift

I'm trying to access this custom obj-C category in Swift file:

```
#import "NSString+UUID.h"

@implementation NSString (UUIDCategory)

+ (NSString*)stringWithUUID 
{
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *string = (NSString*)CFMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid));
    CFRelease(uuid);
    return [string autorelease];    
}

@end
```

So, I added :

```
#import "NSString+UUID.h"
```

in my bridging header, but can't find a solution to use it.

```
var string = NSString.stringWithUUID()
```

**EDIT: the code seems to work now (the problem was I didn't include #import Foundation/Foundation.h in my bridging header before importing my categories.**

Comment: This is a factory method and Swift will create an initializer for you automaticaly! `NSString(UUID:uuid)`

Comment: The compiler wrote: expected module member name after module name.

Comment: Do not edit your question with the answer. Post an actual answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Also what is wrong with `NSUUID().UUIDString`?

Comment: Abhi: I didn't use this Apple method cos' my app was working on iOS 5 also a few months ago... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a factory method and Swift will create an initializer for you automatically!

You should be able to use it like this:

```
 let string = NSString(UUID:uuid)
```

Off topic, but you should really adopt ARC :]

Comment: But I'm in a Swift file... not in an Obj file. ;) I edit my message and found the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but didn't work. This is OK : let string = NSString.stringWithUUID() - This is KO: let string2 = NSString(UUID:uuid) - expected module member name after module name

Comment: Hmm if the initializer syntax didn't work for you it might be because the compiler didn't recognize your factory method to be a factory method. Try changing `(NSString *)` to `(instancetype)` and it should work. Syntax like `NSString.stringWith...` is not what you should use in Swift